# Passing a string from one activity to previous activity

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a string from current activity to previous activity. I tried with intent, but it got failed. how can i pass it? Can anyone help me to find a solution for this?....i struck with this from 4 days... please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please, paste what you have tried and explain why it's failing.

Comment: This is a common task in Android. Have a look at **[Returning a Result from a Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#implementcallbacks)**

Answer (score 6):

before your new activity (B) is finishing, use `setResult()`

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("RESULT", "my string to pass to previous activity");
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

and in the previous activity (A) you must use `startActivityForResult()` for starting the activity B

then in activity A override `onActivityResult()` to retrieve the result.